# How to Compare an RGB Value to Color?

Tags: java, colors, rgb

I'm scanning through the pixels in a `BufferedImage` to see if some of the pixels are a certain color. I've tried this by doing the following:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        if(image.getRGB(x, y) == new Color(209, 167, 86).getRGB()) System.out.println("Same Color Detected!");
    }
}
```

But `image.getRGB()` returns a different value to `Color.getRGB()`. How can I compare them?

These are some examples of the values (first digit is from image, second the colour I'm comparing):

```
0 : -8060928
-16777216 : -8060928
-3037354 : -8060928
-3037354 : -8060928
-16777216 : -8060928
```

Here's how I'm getting the image:

```
playerOrig = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Player/player.gif"));
```

I'm using Eclipse with Java 1.6

I printed out the `ColorModel` of the image and got this:

```
IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 4 numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@45d6a56e transparency = 2 transIndex   = 11 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false
```

I then printed out the `ColorSpace` of the `Color` object and got this:

```
java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@45d6a56e
```

Here's the image:

[image]

Comment: `image.getRGB()` and `Color.getRGB()` both return `int` so forgive my confusion

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry about that, I meant a different value.

Comment: how do they differ, that is the most important part and you left it out!

Comment: Got an example image?  Does it contain alpha values?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm not really sure how they differ, I just know that none of the pixels in the image are the same to that colours I'm comparing them to.

Comment: print out the `int` values and add them to your question so we can see what they are

Comment: You do realise that the sample image you've supplied is 320x320 pixels

Comment: @MadProgrammer I uploaded an enlarged version so you can see it better.

Comment: @sparklyllama Okay, problem is, once I update you code to use the full size of the image, your code works...have the actual image you are using I can test?

Comment: we need the actual original file, otherwise it is comparing apples to oranges blindly.

Comment: Okay, works find for me...

Comment: Post the code for how you are creating the `BufferedImage` object and what JDK version you are using. It looks like one object is including the `alpha` values for the transparency and the other isn't.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I posted that information, not sure if it's exactly what you want.

Comment: the file you sent has a different name, are you sure you are reading the file you expect?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I know I'm using the right image, as I'm rendering the image onto the screen and it's the correct one.

Comment: Try the code I posted with the image 16X16 image you posted with that same name. The two files could be slightly different and you might can not tell the different visually. You should get the same output I am. Since you are reading from the classpath, you might have an old image that is cached in your build dir of your IDE and it isn't actually what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

## Works for me ...

*NOTE: well I tested the code on my local machine and it works for me just fine as you have it with the default `ColorModel`. I am using OSX and `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)` Good Luck!*

### Here is a [link to my entire Mavenized project on GitHub.com](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow)

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Q23751298
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
        //final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/jhr/Pictures/fu4FM.gif"));
        final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(Q23751298.class.getResource("/fu4FM.gif"));
            final int match = new Color(209, 167, 86).getRGB();

            for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
                {
                    final int irgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
                    if (irgb == match)
                    {
                        System.out.format("%d/%d = %d : %d\n", x, y, img.getRGB(x, y), match);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get for the `16 X 16` file you posted:

```
4/9 = -3037354 : -3037354
4/10 = -3037354 : -3037354
4/11 = -3037354 : -3037354
6/4 = -3037354 : -3037354
7/4 = -3037354 : -3037354
7/5 = -3037354 : -3037354
7/6 = -3037354 : -3037354
7/7 = -3037354 : -3037354
8/4 = -3037354 : -3037354
8/5 = -3037354 : -3037354
8/6 = -3037354 : -3037354
8/7 = -3037354 : -3037354
9/4 = -3037354 : -3037354
9/7 = -3037354 : -3037354
10/5 = -3037354 : -3037354
10/6 = -3037354 : -3037354
12/10 = -3037354 : -3037354
12/11 = -3037354 : -3037354
```

Comment: So how can I get values that represent the same thing?

Comment: `new Color(int, boolean)` will create a new `Color` object representing the packed `int` value.  If the `int` value includes an alpha bit, then you want to pass `true`.  You can then use `Color#getRed/Green/Blue` to the inviducal color components

Comment: Yep, I got the same output. I'll create a new image file in the directory.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I think it may have something to do with the fact that the image is being taken in a different method to how you're doing it here.

Comment: @sparklyllama - I put the image on the classpath and loaded if from there, exact same **correct** output. See my edit to the code. The image you are reading isn't the one you think you are, there isn't any other obvious reason. [Working Project on GitHub](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample image you've supplied, you're only inspecting a 16x16 grid of the image, when the image is 320x320 pixels in size...

When I update your code to include the full width and height of the image, it works just fine...

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
    Color match = new Color(209, 167, 86);

    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (img.getRGB(x, y) == match.getRGB()) {
                System.out.println("Same Color Detected!");
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Updated**

Based on the new, smaller, example the code still works...

To prove it, I wrote a simple color replacement algorithim...

[image: Original][image: Replaced]
[image: Original][image: Replaced]

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("8bit.gif"));
    BufferedImage replaced = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Color match = new Color(209, 167, 86);
    Color with = new Color(0, 255, 0);

    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            int pixel = img.getRGB(x, y);
            if (pixel == match.getRGB()) {
                System.out.println("Same Color Detected!");
                replaced.setRGB(x, y, with.getRGB());
            } else {
                replaced.setRGB(x, y, pixel);
            }
        }
    }

    ImageIO.write(replaced, "png", new File("replaced.png"));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(replaced)));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The colour replacement is exactly what I'm doing, and I have the exact same code as you, and it doesn't work for me. Not sure what's going on here...

Comment: @sparklyllama Without context, it's difficult to know. The `image` reference you have may not be what you're expecting, the `image` may be created using some weird color space...