# Read RGB component values((255,255,255)) of pixels from PNG

Tags: java, python, image-processing, colors, rgb

I am trying to find a way to get RGB values( R, G, B component ranging from 0 to 255) of pixels from a PNG file. In python its something like:

```
import Image
im = Image.open("dead_parrot.jpg") #Can be many different formats.
pix = im.load()
print im.size #Get the width and hight of the image for iterating over
print pix[x,y] #Get the RGBA Value of the a pixel of an image
pix[x,y] = value # Set the RGBA Value of the image (tuple)
```

I am trying to find the same functionality in Java. I tried:

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y).
```

But it is giving unexpected values like -167667. Where as what I need is a tuple like (255,255,255). I am unable to transform the output of getRGB to this tuple like value from where I can pick the R, G and B component separately.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751298/how-to-compare-an-rgb-value-to-color/23751541#23751541)?

Comment: getRGB is not giving correct RGB values.

Comment: `getRGB` will give you a packed `int`, if you want to get the individual color components, you can use `Color(int, boolean)` where `int` is the RGB value and `boolean` determines if the `int` value contains a alpha component or not.  Remember, Java `int`s are signed `ints` so you may get overflow's where the `int` value negative...

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: You need to bit-shift and mask out values in order to get the individual pixels.  The pixels are packed in 8 bits side by side.  As such, if you did `int color = image.getRGB(x,y);`, if you want the red component, you would do `int red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;`, for green: `int green= (color >> 8) & 0xFF;`, for blue: `int blue = color & 0xFF;`

Comment: @VikasBansal: People in Java-land (like me) have been using `BufferedImage.getRGB()` for ages, so it's unlikely that it doesn't work, or give wrong values. Instead, you probably expect it to return something else. It would help if you focus on describing what you expect, vs. actual results. Preferably using a an example, as suggested by @MadProgrammer.

Comment: @haraldK: Yeah I wanted the specific RGB values and I guess it was giving me something related to that but not exactly what I wanted. I specifically mentioned in my post that I want the same functionality as mentioned on python code snippet "#Get the RGBA Value of the a pixel of an image". I dont know why I was downvoted.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yes I wanted the individual RGB components as provided by "print pix[x,y] #Get the RGBA Value of the a pixel of an image" in the python code I pasted. I guess the output was clear, please explain why I was downvoted.

Comment: @haraldK: By incorrect I meant it is not giving the specific RGB values. I had no intention to hurt the population in Java land. :D

Comment: @VikasBansal: Not feeling hurt, just that the question isn't clear. If you  can explain (update your question, don't comment) a) What do you man by "specific RGB values", b) In what way does `getRGB(x,y)` give "wrong values" (feel free to rephrase to "unexpected"), and finally c) State clearly what values/types you expect *in Java*, then I will consider voting for re-open. :-)

Comment: @haraldK: Please see now, I guess it much more clear now. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: If you check  the example in the answer, you will see that I use Color(int, boolean) which gives me a Color object, from here you can use Color#getRed/Green/Blue to get the individual color components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using this image...

[image: Test]

And this code...

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);

    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
            System.out.println(rgb + " = " + new Color(rgb, true));
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

It produces this (sample) output...

```
0 = java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
-16777216 = java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
-12779519 = java.awt.Color[r=61,g=0,b=1]
-12779519 = java.awt.Color[r=61,g=0,b=1]
-12779519 = java.awt.Color[r=61,g=0,b=1]
-16777216 = java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
```

So unless you can provide and example (code and image) which is giving you the incorrect output and the expectations of the output, it's difficult to know what else to suggest

Comment: is pixel 0,0 at bottom left of screen or top left?

Comment: oh i see it in the doc ` objects have an upper left corner
 * coordinate of (0,&nbsp;0)`

Answer (score 1):

In java, use `ImageIO.read("mypic.png")` to get a `BufferedImage`. After that you can use `getData()` method which will give you Raster Object on which you can call `getPixel`.

Comment: What's wrong with `BufferedIamge#getRGB`...?

Comment: Nothing, but getPixel() is somewhat faster than getRGB().